# Gaussian Integers and Finite Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, finite-fields, gaussian-integers

I have been doing a little reading in elementary number theory, in particular I was reading about the Gaussian Integer, $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. My question regards the algebraic structure of $$\frac{\mathbb{Z}[i]}{p \mathbb{Z}[i]} $$ where $p$ is a prime in both $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. In particular I am asking if there are any analogies I can draw from the finite field $$\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p \mathbb{Z}} $$
where $p$ is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}.$ It is well known that $$\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p \mathbb{Z}} $$ is a finite field iff $p$ is prime. Can anything be said $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[i]}{p \mathbb{Z}[i]}$? My hunch is that there are also finite fields. If they are, is there a way I can compute them?

Comment: Yes, it's a field, because the ideal $(p)$ will also be maximal in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Since $p$ must be congruent to $3$ modulo $4$, but the quotient contains a square root of $-1$, it is the field of $p^2$ elements.

Comment: You must have $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ because we are assuming that $p$ is a prime in *both* $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. The primes with that property are precisely the ones that are congruent to $3$ modulo $4$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Can you elaborate more on the field being of $p^2$ elements please?

Comment: It is trivially of characteristic $p$ and of order at most $p^2$ (since it is generated by $2$ elements, so it is at most two dimensional as a vector space); but because the field of order $p$ does not contain a square root of $-1$ for $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, then it must be a quadratic extension of that field, i.e., the field of $p^2$ elements.

Comment: If you happen to find this more concrete, this is the same field as $\mathbb Z_p[x]/(x^2+1)$, with $i$ playing the role of the indeterminate $x$.  The condition on $p$ is necessary for $x^2+1$ to be irreducible mod $p$.

Comment: @ErickWong If you don't mind can you tease out the isomorphism?

Comment: @AnIsomorphicTeen Well, on one side you have elements that look like $a+bi$ where $a,b$ can be taken as elements of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$.  On the other side you have polynomials of degree $\le 1$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, i.e. $bx + a$.  The isomorphism is literally just mapping $a+bi$ to $bx+a$.

Comment: I see, and on the first side $p$ is assumed to be a prime in both $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ correct?

Comment: @AnIsomorphicTeen Both sides make sense whether or not $p$ is (doubly) prime, but having $p\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ gives you a field rather than just a ring on either side.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you that isomorphism is really helpful.